# using a List<> inside a foreach

Tags: c#

I created a List called people that holds an identification number, name, title, and city. I would like to automate the reading out of this list using a foreach but am a little stuck on the syntax. Can someone shed a little light on it. Below is my code.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

Person p1 = new Person(74, "Brad","Millington","Program Manager", "Milford");
Person p2 = new Person(58, "John", "Kaufman", "Author", "Ottawa");
Person p3 = new Person(68, "-*", "Washington" , "Developer", "Redmond");
Person p4 = new Person(79, "Abraham", "Licoln", "Developer", "Redmond");

foreach (string s in people)
{
    people.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: You need to supply us with the format of that list as you are apparently only scanning a list/array of strings

Comment: Your List is empty, you created 4 Persons but never added them to the list

Comment: -1 please revise the question and the code, it makes no sense.

Comment: What are you trying to read? In your example, there's nothing in the list, but you're trying to add strings to it. Which doesn't work, since it's not a list of strings. And I should have refreshed before commenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your people list is currently empty at the beginning

You would want to add your p1, p2, p3 and p4 to the people list

```
Person p1 = new Person(74, 'Brad', 'Millington', 'Program Manager', 'Milford');
people.add(p1);
```

Then in your for each if you are printing them out i assume you have a getter for the name

```
foreach (Person p in people) 
{
    Console.Write(p.getFirstName() + ' ' + p.getLastName());
}
```

I have not done any C# myself but this should work based on my experience with Java

Comment: `print` doesn't exist in C#.  Use `Console.Write` instead.  Also, Properties aren't called like methods.  Other than that, this is correct.

Comment: +1 for getting it right without knowing any C#.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Yes, but you can easily create a function `print` that does what you want.

Comment: Just as an additional note on idiom, to underscore @KyleTrauberman's point: The first and last names would more likely be expressed as properties, so `Console.Write(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName);`

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the other correct answers, I note that a nicer way to create your test data is to use a *collection initializer*:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() 
{
    new Person(74, "Brad","Millington","Program Manager", "Milford"),
    new Person(58, "John", "Kaufman", "Author", "Ottawa"),
    new Person(68, "-*", "Washington" , "Developer", "Redmond"),
    new Person(79, "Abraham", "Licoln", "Developer", "Redmond")
};

foreach (Person person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `foreach` statement is used to loop through an enumerable which has data, not to fill the collection in the first place.  You can't loop through something with no items - in your case, you're trying to do a "for each "s" in people" but people is empty because you haven't added anything to it yet.

If you're trying to add the 4 people to your list, you need to just add them directly:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

people.Add(new Person(74, "Brad","Millington","Program Manager", "Milford"));
people.Add(new Person(58, "John", "Kaufman", "Author", "Ottawa"));
people.Add(new Person(68, "-*", "Washington" , "Developer", "Redmond"));
people.Add(new Person(79, "Abraham", "Licoln", "Developer", "Redmond"));
```

(Note that you can also use collection initialization syntax if you prefer...)

Once the people are added, you can then loop over them, and print out as needed:

```
foreach(Person person in people)
    Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName);
```

Note that, at this point, the loop will loop and give you a `Person` instance each iteration, not a string.  In order to have the foreach as you wrote, you'd have to have an implicit conversion to string (which I wouldn't recommend) for the `Person` class.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there are a few things wrong with your code:

1. `people` is a list of `Person` objects, so iterating over it as a list of strings will give you a compile error.
2. You can not modify the collection that is being iterated over when using `foreach`. You are doing this by using `.Add()` inside the loop.
3. `people` is empty, so the loop won't execute anyways.

This code will compile, and write the first and last name of each person the the console:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

Person p1 = new Person(74, "Brad","Millington","Program Manager", "Milford");
Person p2 = new Person(58, "John", "Kaufman", "Author", "Ottawa");
Person p3 = new Person(68, "-*", "Washington" , "Developer", "Redmond");
Person p4 = new Person(79, "Abraham", "Licoln", "Developer", "Redmond");

people.Add(p1);
people.Add(p2);
people.Add(p3);
people.Add(p4);

foreach (Person p in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list Initializer:

```
var people = new List<Person>{
    new Person(74, "Brad","Millington","Program Manager", "Milford"),
    new Person(58, "John", "Kaufman", "Author", "Ottawa"),
    new Person(68, "-*", "Washington" , "Developer", "Redmond"),
    new Person(79, "Abraham", "Licoln", "Developer", "Redmond")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to populate a list then read out its values in a foreach loop.  If that's what you want to do, then the core of the question is: "what is a string representation of my object?"

For example, if you were calling `p.ToString()` where `p` is a `Person`, by default you would get its type name.  When creating objects, it is sometimes useful to override the `ToString()` method of the implied base class for `Person`, i.e. `System.Object`.  Beware that when you do override the `ToString()` method, the compiler will warn you if you don't also override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`.